# Python is mounted hangs with stale mount. Suggestions?

Tags: python, mount

I ran into a problem today where a mount went stale and this caused my entire python application to hang indefinitely.

What happened is the mount went stale, and then I called `os.path.exists(path)` on that path. The call hangs indefinitely.

I really really need to prevent this. My only idea is to put the `os.path.exists` call on a background thread and kill the thread abruptly (obviously not preferred) if it's still alive after a timeout amount of seconds. Ideally I would avoid this by making a call to check if the mount is stale first.

Any ideas? FYI, all calls that try to access this path hang including `os.path.ismount(path)`. While this is a rare event, I can't have my entire system freezing on users :/.

Comment: I've seen this behavior with some custom file systems (fuse etc.).  It looks more like an issue of the file system implementation, which stops giving answers when the kernel asks.  I'd re-tag the question as Linux, Kernel (if applicable).

Comment: This is in ubuntu mounting a remote centOS drive (nfs I believe). No weird file systems. We're trying the "soft" nfs mounting option currently, but haven't come across the mount going stale yet to test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python subprocess module and shell "timeout" command to detect the hange mount:

```
call = subprocess.Popen(["timeout 10 ls /your_mount_dir/ &> /dev/null; echo $?"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = call.communicate()
result = output[0].strip()
if result != '0':
   # Mount is hung.
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [myheartsgoon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45428377/3209889)'s answer, but safer and more simple.

```
try:
    subprocess.check_call(["timeout", "4", "ls", "/mnt/your_nas"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    # is hanging
```